# WPF UserControl throwing "Input string was not in a correct format." on InitializeComponent after migrating to .netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Just migrated an existing WPF application to .netcore 3.1 from .net framework 4.8, when it tries to start up now I get the exception on any control that is loaded.  It's happening when InitializeComponent is called.

The exception starts at line 1 on the xaml, even with completely unmodified xaml from a newly created control.  I can post code snippets, but in an attempt to narrow it down I'm using a control that was just created with no modifications at all.

I've tried debugging into it further but can't seem to find what it's actually complaining about.

The error code is  XDG0062, and is being shown on the designer view of the xaml file that consumes the controls.

Anyone have any tips on where to dig further?

Comment: Look at the start of the file in a hex editor / notepad++. Any special characters (like a UTF-16 BOM) in there?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately nothing visible or invisible.

Comment: Just found something that might be helpful, looking at the xaml of the window that adds the control it's showing the same error while underlined in light blue.  That xaml wasn't changed, so not sure why it's suddenly an issue.

`xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:OTA.Scoring.UI.Controls"`

and

`<controls:ConnectionStatusIndicatorControl x:Name="ApiConnectionStatusIcon" Width="15" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="330,36,0,0" />`

Comment: Check the CultureInfo

Comment: @WillParsons is there string format provided in Xaml ?

Comment: @Tony - no culture info being set at all, could that be an issue?

Comment: @SatishPai - no string formats provided at all, the "controls" line is the offending line being highlighted.

Comment: Is it possible to share the xaml screen shot ? or any piece of code

Comment: The code is in the comment above, I've also tried with a brand new control in the same namespace with no options set to it

`<controls:TestControl />` and get the same error.

None of the errors were there before migrating it to the new project file format and .netcore3.1, so it's definitely some sort of compatibility issue.  I'm just baffled as to how when even a completely empty new control has the same issue.

Comment: I've even added a brand new empty window, and then added the brand new empty control to that window to rule out any possible issues with my existing base classes, etc.  Same exact issue.

Adding a brand new WPF project, then new window and new control (same structure) seems to fix it, I'll have to scan the project file to see what might be causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that was a giant weird mess.

The issue ended up being two lines in the project file, it was nothing to do with the controls or window XAML at all.

`<AssemblyVersion>1.2.*</AssemblyVersion>
<FileVersion>1.2.*</FileVersion>`